# Passing program arguments through Cargo

Tags: rust

I have some sample code that is currently making use of [getopts](https://crates.io/crates/getopts) which is specified as a dependency in `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
getopts = "0.2"
```

However I can not seem to pass argument (`-t`, `--test`) through Cargo (e.g. `cargo run --test`) for obvious reasons.

Since I have specified that external dependency, trying to run `rustc src/main.rs --test` won't work either:

```
src/main.rs:2:5: 2:21 error: unresolved import `getopts::Options`. There is no `Options` in `getopts`
src/main.rs:2 use getopts::Options;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Is there another way to achieve this or some common alternative for the time being?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can pass trailing arguments to `cargo run` using `--`:

```
cargo run -- --test
```

From the `man` page:

> All of the trailing arguments are passed to the binary to run. If you're passing
>   arguments to both Cargo and the binary, the ones after `--` go to the binary,
>   the ones before go to Cargo.

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution; should start reading the man page more often :-)

Comment: @Juxhin: Note that it's commonly used in a number of Unix tools that invoke other programs; so it's good to know in general.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you had two different problems.
First is, how to pass flags to your executable (this was solved by @TartanLlama), the second is your compile error.

For future reference (this is at least true for my system with rust 1.19, cargo 0.20):
You used an external crate `getopts`, which `rustc` by default does not know.
`cargo` on the other hand understands that.
By running `cargo rustc` (or even better `cargo build`) instead of `rustc` the compile error will vanish.