# Can a build script take arguments?

Tags: rust

I was going through [the build script documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) and was wondering if I can pass any argument to the script in `build.rs` from the command line.

```
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let var = &args[1];
}
```

Would something like this work in the build script? And how could I specify the arguments from command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Documentation suggests passing data to the build script using environment variables.

There is no documentation indicating that it can be done and [the test suite does not test for it](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/master/tests/testsuite/build_script.rs). It only tests for [environment variables](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/master/tests/testsuite/build_script_env.rs).

I attempted the method that @Stephan suggests from [Passing program arguments through Cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400231/passing-program-arguments-through-cargo), however `cargo build` does not follow the same behavior as `cargo run`:

```
$ cargo build -- uoeuoe
error: Found argument 'uoeuoe' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    cargo.exe build [OPTIONS]

For more information try --help
```