# How can I make running a Cargo build script optional?

Tags: build, rust, rust-cargo

I have a Rust project that generates a dynamic (cdylib) library. The project uses a [cbindgen](https://crates.io/crates/cbindgen) build script to create an according C header file, matching the exported functions of the library. `Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "example"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Me <me@foo.bar>"]
build = "build.rs"

[lib]
name = "example"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]

[build-dependencies]
cbindgen = "0.6.2"
```

Unfortunately RLS (Rust Language Server) doesn't work very well when the build script is active which makes editing in VS Code rather unpleasant. Is there a way to make running the build script optional, having it disabled by default and only manually enable it when requested on the command-line (i.e. something like `cargo build --release --enable-build-scripts`)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51678337/493729. I believe the answer is to use environment variables

Comment: @PeterHall: Is it possible to use a feature entry to enable/disable build dependencies? As features are forwarded from Cargo command-line to environment variables during build this seems to combine well with your suggestion.

Comment: I haven't tried that - perhaps let us know if you can make it work! I think environment variables are pretty convenient by themselves.

Comment: Unfortunately the Windows `cmd` shell doesn't support adding environment variables as a prefix to the actual command line. Thus I was looking for some solution based on Cargo "features".

Comment: _"Unfortunately the Windows cmd shell doesn't support adding environment variables as a prefix to the actual command line"_ — How about https://superuser.com/a/950944 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't conditionally disable build scripts or pass variables to them via `cargo build`, but you can make use of environment variables instead.

Inside your `build.rs`:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {  
    let build_enabled = env::var("BUILD_ENABLED")
        .map(|v| v == "1")
        .unwrap_or(true); // run by default

    if build_enabled {
        // do your build
    }
}
```

Build with your build script:

```
BUILD_ENABLED=1 cargo build
```

Build without your build script:

```
BUILD_ENABLED=0 cargo build
```

Answer (score 8):

To extend the answer from @PeterHall one can use a Cargo ["features"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section) section to pass information on to the build script.

Insert the following lines into `Cargo.toml`:

```
[features]
headers = []
```

Then check for environment variable `CARGO_FEATURE_HEADERS` in `build.rs`:

```
use std::env;

fn write_headers() {
    // call cbindgen ...
}

fn main() {
    let headers_enabled = env::var_os("CARGO_FEATURE_HEADERS").is_some();
    if headers_enabled {
        write_headers();
    }
}
```

To make a release build run `cargo build --features=headers --release`.

Now this solution still compiles the build script and all cbindgen dependencies when RLS updates its status or when manually running `cargo test`. But cbindgen run-time errors do not hamper RLS anymore.

Comment: A separate self-answer is ok too. And you'll get the credit. I did't know that Cargo features got translated into environment vars like that!