# Print file name from standard input

Tags: rust, input

I am trying to save the filename from the standard input as a string. In my research so far I have only found the ability to read the file data as a whole string or line by line but nothing for getting the exact text written as the standard input.

When executing my code I am doing:

```
cargo run < filename.csv
```

I am expecting my output to be `filename.csv` but instead I am getting this: `Stdin { .. }`

My inclination is there should be some way to "catch" the input before it is going to start reading the bytes for my file, but I am lost here.

This is the code I am running. I read the whole input as a string trying to grep through it for the file extension (.csv) but I did not find anything:

```
let stdin = io::read_to_string(io::stdin());
println!("{:?}",stdin);
```

Comment: you forgot to add the `--` to the run subcommand: `cargo run -- < filename.csv`.
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing program arguments through Cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400231/passing-program-arguments-through-cargo)

Comment: Sorry it did not but I managed to work around it using the answer from ᏗᎷᏒᎧシ

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To print the file name from standard input in Rust, you can make use of the std::env::args function. This function returns an iterator over the command-line arguments passed to the program.

Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how to achieve this:

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    
    if let Some(file_name) = args.get(1) {
        println!("{}", file_name);
    } else {
        eprintln!("No file name provided.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if this helped the OP, this was a mistake in the question but this answer is incorrect for this question. When you redirect stdin you don't get additional args.

Comment: @Mypantsrtoobig your question asks about a pipe/standard input redirection. I spent some time doing research to address exactly that case *as written in your question*. Can you elaborate on why this is the correct answer, given that it's answering regarding args while your question is asking about redirections?

Answer (score 3):

On most typical shells on Linux-esque operating systems, your binary (rust or otherwise) doesn't know where its standard output is coming from in this case. The shell is responsible for opening a file descriptor of `filename.csv` for read and ensuring that it's the standard input of the process it then launches (on Linux, this is file descriptor 0).

Getting the filename is not necessarily possible (e.g. standard input could be an anonymous pipe), and it may not point to a file (e.g. it may point to a pty on Linux); furthermore, the process of getting a filename is system-depdendent.

On Linux, you can use [`std::fs::read_link`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_link.html) with `/proc/self/fd/0`, with the understanding that it may not be a filename. On my Linux box, I get filenames, `/dev/pts/...`, and `pipe:[...]` as outputs when quickly testing.

On Windows, you can use a combination of `GetStdHandle` and `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`, but both of these require unsafe code, and `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` takes raw pointers due to how its C API is designed, hence being much more annoying to use. I'm not certain whether this functionality is available in a crate. I briefly looked through the NT object namespace in hopes of a similar trick to `/proc/` above, but couldn't locate anything there.